# Can we use Cassandra in place of Hadoop with Spark?

Tags: database-design, cassandra, application-design, hadoop, apache-spark

Considering we have a backend written in NodeJS and uses MySQL and Cassandra as it's databases, if we want to add Spark to the system to do some data analyzing stuff like recommendation, can we do it with Cassandra( I mean using Spark + Cassandra) and reach the same result as we could reach with the Hadoop( Spark + Hadoop)?

I want to know what Hadoop can do that Cassandra can not to? Or what would make it essential to use Hadoop alongside with the Spark?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use Spark directly to perform real-time analytics on your Cassandra database using the [Spark Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector).

Most tech giants use this combination for use cases that include recommender engines, personalisation, show what's trending, and fraud detection all in real-time.

Note that we recommend running analytics on a different Cassandra data centre so online user transactions are not affected by the analytics queries. For example, route app traffic to DC1 while Spark apps read/write to DC2 to isolate analytics and OLTP workloads in their own DCs. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Are there also use cases that we shouldn't use Cassandra or it's better to use Hadoop instead? I like to know more about the distinctions between Cassandra and Hadoop. What can one do and another can't do?

Comment: They are two different things so you can't compare them. Cassandra is a database used for high velocity use cases at very large scale. Although Hadoop can store data, it is not a database but a framework for analytics over large datasets. Cheers!